# .NET Web API 2 Project downloading browserLink.js

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, signalr

I've got a .NET Web API project and on load I'm getting a download of this script called browserLink.

```
 http://localhost:49818/ea93983f23c54f35a63de09646c09159/browserLink
```

Its associated with .NET Signalr but I'm not using that so I'm not sure why its being included.  Any ideas how to turn it off?

Comment: That is a debugging helper script from Visual Studio, it won't be downloaded in production. To disable it on your local machine check this guide - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/28/browser-link-feature-in-visual-studio-preview-2013.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable Browser Link in Visual Studio 2013.

Do this by editing your web.config file to add the following line to your `appSettings` section:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="vs:EnableBrowserLink" value="false"/>
</appSettings>
```

Note that Browser Link is only used when working in Visual Studio AND the web application is compiled in debug mode, i.e.:

```
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" />
</system.web>
```

In other words, end-users of your site will never make this request.